# jquery: No duplicate select of the same value of many drop down menus

Tags: jquery, validation

I create a form that contains a button to add a new drop down menu (select) "I want to validate that there is no duplicate value selected" before submitting the form, Now I did via below code

jQuery method:

```
$('select').on('change', function(){
$("select").not(this).find("option[value="+ $(this).val() + "]").prop('disabled', true);
```

});

But now I have two problems:

1- If i delete one of the selects its value still disabled in all the others

2- Starting fresh with the original menu then adding for example 5 new menus
the code works fine I mean without duplicated values in all the 6 menus But if I add a new one (the 7th menu) I can select any value even if its selected by the first 6 menus

Any Help ?

UPDATE:

Here is the link to JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/Somayah/oetx6f6c/

Comment: after adding the select check for disabled option in it and remove disbaled property of that particular option

Comment: Can we see an example with markup? JSFiddle maybe?

Comment: @wrxsti check it plz :")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get something working like this: [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/oetx6f6c/5/)

```
var disabled = [];
var disableOptions = function () {
  //console.log(disabled);
    $('option').prop('disabled', false);
    $.each(disabled, function(key, val){
        $('option[value="' + val + '"]').prop('disabled', true);
    });
};

$('.moreAttendence').click(function () {
    var box_html = $('select:first').clone();
    $('.more-box').append('<br />');
    $('.more-box').append(box_html);
    box_html.fadeIn('slow');

    disableOptions();
});

$(document).on('change', 'select', function () {
    disabled = [];
    $('select').each(function(){
        if($(this).val() != 'none'){
            $('option').prop('disabled', false);
            disabled.push( $(this).val() );
        }
    });
    disableOptions();
});
```

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: In which way? I will see what I can do.

Comment: @wrxsti there is no validation among them you can select the same value in all the menus you have added, But I really appreciate your effort :)

Comment: I will have something for you momentarily. Also I removed the validation you had because I didn't have the library readily available, and it was entirely relevant to the change method.

Comment: I want to allow no duplicated selects among all of them and in case of deleting one of the menus it's value change to enable so you can select it again that's all :)